# Determine if Email send was canceled

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

There are two add ins in my Outlook 2010 application. The first application is mine and the second is owned by someone else. Both applications use the Send event to do their work. The second application (not mine), sometimes, cancels the send event. Since my code has already run, that makes things bad for me as I save data to another service.

I can't re-order the event calls (policy), so... how can I determine if a send was not canceled? I can't find an after send event and the close event isn't called on send.

I want to run my code once I know, for sure, that the send went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the item close event was not being called but the inspector closed event was called after the send event. I re-structured my code and placed the saving code in the inspectors closed event.